# How to keep application like a browser in front when sharing a link?

Tags: android

I don't seem to be lucky enough to hit the right keywords, so that I could find out what is the preferred way to prevent an application from being brought to front when sharing a link from a browser.

In my AndroidManifest.xml I've the required Intent filter and my application receives a link just fine, but I'd like to stay in the browser of my choice after the sharing.

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
<data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Alternatively, I'd like to be asked by my application "to what predefined category I would like put the shared link".

Answer (score 0):

After considering this for a moment, it began to make sense to create another activity, which would be

- fully transparent and without any titles etc. when I just need a link to be saved quickly - and then just call finish() to hide the activity or
- partially transparent from its sides, when I want to make a choice before saving a link.

Simple preparations for the latter one:

1. Set a custom theme for the activity:

   ```
   android:theme="@style/windowNoTitle"
   ```
2. Use a style resource:

   ```
   <style name="windowNoTitle" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
   <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
   <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
   <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
   <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
   </style>
   ```
3. Add margin:

   ```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_margin="50dp"
         android:orientation="horizontal">
   ```